# LWJGL Tutorials

Tags: java, lwjgl

Does anyone know of any good Light Weight Java Game Library tutorials geared towards beginners in OpenGL? I have noticed there are some on youtube but they only cover the basics on creating a window and redering 2D quads to the screen, and are often incomplete. Also the LWJGL website offers small tutorials, but only, it seems, on the basics of setting up the window and polling input.

Any suggestions would be welcome.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

These are some of the links for your interest:

http://content.gpwiki.org/index.php/OpenGL:Tutorials:Java:LWJGL:Introduction

http://lwjgl.org/forum/index.php?topic=3616.0

http://ninjacave.com/lwjglapplet

http://code.google.com/p/lwjgltutorial/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2Fsrc%2Forg%2Flwjgltutorial%253Fstate%253Dclosed

http://www.experiencefestival.com/wp/videos/18-advanced-opengl-rendering--java-game-development-lwjgl/oTqFgYR3Fvs - This is nice video tutorial.Also, this is the following site that collected more than 18 lessons of the source of the video tutorial.
https://github.com/OskarVeerhoek/YouTube-tutorials/tree/master/src.

http://www.lloydgoodall.com/tutorials/first-person-camera-control-with-lwjgl/ - tutorial for first person camera controller

https://bitbucket.org/chuck/lwjgl-sandbox/src/b3e538e59c85/src/main/java/tutorials/nehe - This one is having around 12 lessons of NEHE ported to LWGJL.

Answer (score 6):

I always watch TheCodingUniverse when he releases new tutorials with LWJGL, here's episode 1: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0v56I5UWrYY (He has currently released 26 episodes: from basic 2D quads to  advanced rendering, sound and loading models)

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommend reading [Learning Modern 3D Graphics Programming](http://www.arcsynthesis.org/gltut/index.html).
If you are interested in the LWJGL port you can find it [here](https://github.com/integeruser/jgltut).